# Javascript JSON.parse function with Ajax request and "\\n" new line escaped char

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, escaping

https://jsbin.com/zuhatujoqo/1/edit?js,console

Edit: json file has this line:

```
{"pd":"ciao \\n ste"}
```

I'm requesting a valid json file with an ajax call.
Then JSON.parse the result.

I don't understand what is happening with the "\\n" escaped new line char coming from my json file.

JSON.parse is giving me different result if i feed it with the same values.

```
var result = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(result);
var result2 = JSON.parse('{"pd":"ciao \\n ste"}');
console.log(result2);
```

As i understand it may be related to the fact that javascript before and then parse are escaping ( or unescaping ?? ) the string.

The problem is that i also don't understand this:

```
result = result.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");
```

do i also have to escape the regex itself?

Sum: I want to use the .json file loaded via Ajax.
I want the JSON.parse to do his job and unescape the "\\n" returning the NewLine char.

Comment: Backslashes are escaped in JSON. in JS string literals and in JS regex literals, so if you want to get a backslash in your parsed output you need to double-escape it (`JSON.parse("\\\\")`).

Comment: What exactly is `data`? You propbably should fix your server if it doesn't send the expected values, instead of trying to do some replacements on the client side.

Comment: I made an edit to also include the .json file content. when i inspect data variable within chrome console i see that is holding the exact same content of the .json file. I don't understand why the "\\n" inside the json is not turning (after json.parse(data) into a new line char but instead into a "\n". Instead if you try to JSON.parse directly in javascript the string ( instead of loading it trhough ajax)   var result2 = JSON.parse('{"pd":"ciao \\n ste"}'); it is indeed turning the"\\n" into a new line char.

Comment: Yes, but your string literal does not have the same content as the JSON file (because of string literal escaping), therfore your results are different from each other.

Comment: You should have `\n` in that JSON (or a real newline), not `\\n`. You can remove it on the client side (`data.replace(/\\\\n/, "\\n")`), but you really should fix this issue on the server side.

Comment: wait really? i tought Json requires you to escape control characters, \ and '

Comment: OK, strike that "*(or a real newline)*", it's rubbish. You're right, control characters must be escaped.

Comment: Well i'm starting to understand what's going on here a litte more thanks to your help. I'm now going to sleep. But i still don't understand what's happening with the string literals nor i understand  how this is working "You can remove it on the client side (data.replace(/\\\\n/, "\\n"))" it look that it is inserting back \\n again ?

Comment: You can't put a backslash in a string literal, you have to escape it. To make a string `\n`, you have to write the literal `"\\n"`

Comment: I went back to look how i was generating the Json file. I tought I was the one escaping the newlines. It turns out that at the source they write the file with "\\n"  http://puu.sh/op8dt/a9a31db4fe.png so when i make the json file it is just copying that untouched string right?Now In my ajax response what is xmlhttp.responseText an object? a string? somethingelse?

Comment: `.responseText` is a string, but taken literally from the body of the response, without considering any escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers Bergi gave me, i now understand that the JSON.parse was already doing his job.
It was my fault, i was providing a json file with "\\n" inside instead of just "\n".

Here an updated jsbin where you can see that now JSON.parse acts the same in different scenario.
https://jsbin.com/xezipucili/1/edit?js,console